# Microsoft Identity Platform with web application (In Python)***

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

I have been working with 'Integration of Microsoft Identity Platform with a Python web application' ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp). I am trying to access the graph API by Microsoft with the help of a python web application.

To be quick , my problem is : After success acceptance of credentials of microsoft account, it's showing me this issue on web page : **We're unable to complete your request:invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.**

I tried looking at many solutions, but none of them worked.  I tried this solution too - 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-uwp/issues/15

But it is not solving the issue for python. Issue remains the same.

I did everything as per the instructions -

1. Download python project from microsoft graph api docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp)
2. Registered in the Azure App registration.
3. Authentication - Redirect Uri - http://localhost:5000/getAToken ( url suggested by docs)
   -> I added same url in azure, I also tried putting 'https' and 'http' both.
4. Obtained the secret key. (under certificates and secret)
5. Added the required permissions.
6. I changed the app.config file taking all details from my azure app registration ( I am adding the code below ) 
   7.I did not change anything in my app.py file.
7. Started Flask server and finally opened the required localhost address.

Please help me where I went wrong and what corrections I have to make. I'll really appreciate it.
Thanking you in advance.

**App.config**

```
import os

CLIENT_SECRET = "my key" 

AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"  # For multi-tenant app

CLIENT_ID = "my id here"

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"    

ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'  

SCOPE = ["User.ReadBasic.All"]

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # So token cache will be stored in server-side session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved ,always check these  :

1. When you created the app registration, you need to select for supported account types: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD Ddirectory-multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts.
2. Enter your redirect URI in Web configuration, I was doing in SPA which was wrong.
3. Instead of typing http://127.0.0.1:5000/ type 'http://localhost:5000/' in browser. I know it's same but it made a difference for me.
4. You cannot use a free microsoft account for Azure active directory, you have to use paid premium version. You can give card details and use it for a month for free.

hope it helps. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

i just tried the sample you posted, and it worked fine for me.

assuming that you are sure that flask is running on port 5000,

Please try to change your authority URL to https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenantid

i tried with common and it failed . with a different message. but similar.

Comment: yes i am sure it's running on port 5k otherwise the page wudn't load only.

Comment: I previously tried running with the url with my tenenat-id only but it showed me this error -" Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application,The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account. " The only soln i found working for me was to go with 'common'. so How to correct this?

Comment: ah... that changes things.. when you created the app registration, you need to select for supported account types: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD Ddirectory-multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype,Xbox)

Comment: I tried this solution after you told me but unfortunately this is also not working. May it is because of I am using Microsoft account to login instead or work/school accounts. I found this on other forum questions. Is this is the issue?